# Color plot with specified axes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a vector with time points, a vector with frequency points (log-scale) and a (M,N)-matrix where M is the number of frequencies and N is the number of time points.

I want to make a plot where x-axis is the time vector, y-axis is the frequency vector (which is in log-scale) and each point has a color determined by the corresponding value in the matrix.

I have been looking at matplotlib's imshow, but I can't seem to get it working, nor can I find a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `pcolormesh` instead of `imshow`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m, n = 20, 30

# Generate randomly spaced, but increasing time and frequency vectors
time = np.random.normal(0, 1, n).cumsum()
frequency = np.random.normal(0, 1, m).cumsum()
data = np.random.random((m,n))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(time, frequency, data, cmap='gist_earth')
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looked much better, worked perfectly wit my data. Thanks!